# Subtracting specific last word from map

Tags: javascript

I have company names that I loop through and create abbreviations using the code below

```
dataset.nodes.forEach(d => {d.name = d.fullName.split(' ').map(w => w[0]).join('')});
```

Lloyds banking group PLC would be an example of a company and I would like to check if the last word is PLC/plc/p.l.c. and delete it before creating abbreviation because right now the abbreviation of this company would be LBGP and i would want it to be LBG

data:

```
    var dataset = {"nodes":[{"fullName":"Anglo American plc"},{"fullName":"Whitbread PLC"}],"edges":[{"source":0,"target":29,"officers":["MEDORI, Rene"]},{"source":0,"target":30,"officers":["GROTE, Byron Elmer"]},{"source":0,"target":31,"officers":["GROTE, Byron Elmer"]},{"source":1,"target":13,"officers":["BASON, John George"]},{"source":1,"target":18,"officers":["HAUSER, Wolfhart Gunnar, Dr"]},{"source":1,"target":27,"officers":["SINCLAIR, Charles James Francis"]},{"source":2,"target":14,"officers":["COURT, Annette Elizabeth"]},{"source":3,"target":11,"officers":["GREEN, Andrew James"]},{"source":3,"target":12,"officers":["PUSEY, Stephen Charles"]},{"source":3,"target":15,"officers":["KENNEDY, Christopher John"]},{"source":3,"target":24,"officers":["CHAMBERS, Stuart John"]},{"source":3,"target":31,"officers":["CHAMBERS, Stuart John"]},{"source":3,"target":32,"officers":["KENNEDY, Christopher John"]},{"source":4,"target":8,"officers":["BARKER, Glyn"]},{"source":4,"target":12,"officers":["WHEWAY, Jonathan Scott"]}]};
```

Comment: show some examples, data?

Comment: Looks like a job for a _RegExp_, `/\W(plc|p\.l\.c\.)/i.test('Lloyds PLC'); // true`, `/\W(plc|p\.l\.c\.)/i.test('Lloyds'); // false`

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz ive added example ..., Paul S. I do understand that it is a job for regex but I'm not sure how to add it to the code that I have shown you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `split`, test the last element against a regexp and then continue with the map:

```
omits = /p\.?l\.?c\.?/i;

dataset.nodes.forEach(d => {
  const parts = d.fullName.split(' ');
  if (omits.test(parts[parts.length-1])) parts.pop();
  d.name = parts . map(w => w[0]).join('')});
});
```

You could in theory do this with a regexp or two:

```
data.nodes.forEach(d =>
  d.name = d.name . replace(omits, '') . match(/\b\w/g) . join('');
);
```

Notice I've omitted the `{}` here, since they are not technically necessary.

Comment: The first method works but it would remove plc even if it was a part of the word? I would want to only remove plc when it is a word on its own and at the end.